# How to create a double graphic using two tables in Tableau

Tags: mysql, graphics, report, tableau-api

I am working with Tableau in order to obtain a report for my company. The report is a sales based one that should include both booking total amount and total number of booking that have been sold.

So, as an example, we have 2 tables right now:

Bookings.

[image: Booking table]

- ID   -- primary key, unique.
- date -- date of booking creation

Payment.

[image: Payment table]

- ID -- primary key, payment id. Unique
- bookingId -- FK. booking Id. Can be repeated.
- Amount    --  Amount paid.
- Date.     -- Date of payment. We can pay a booking in different dates. We can refund (so every time we refund we will have one line for this payment in negative).

What we need:

[image: Graphics table]

We would like to display a graphic report with both data. Price & number of bookings filtering by **both dates**.

We tried to do that using countD and filtering by date from payment table but we get different number of bookings because we can have 1-N payments of 1 booking.

If we filter by booking date, we won't have the same values so it should be nice to combine both filters.

I don't know the viability of this...

Comment: You need to join or bland the tables. You can't achieve the result just by filtering.

Comment: Hello. Tables are already joined.

Comment: in which case plotting by bookingID should already give the result you want.